# using href or routerlink with #

Tags: html, path, href, routerlink

I'm fairly new to changing paths / position of page so I would like a little help on this.

Say, when a button is clicked, I want to scroll down to another portion of the page. (where id of that section is 'xyz') however, I'm using an entirely different component to access that section.

If I were to use href, I can easily do : `href="/app/appid#xyz"`
however, if appid is a variable retrieved from the ts file, how can I insert it into my href?

It's easier to to use `[routerlink]="['app', appid]"` but how can I insert the "#xyz" into my string?

Or is there a completely separate and easier functionality I can use?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the frament attribute:

```
<a [routerLink]="['app', appid] fragment="xyz">Link</a>
```

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Comment: That fragment was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!